# htaccess to append a query string to all URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I need to append /?test=1 to every single URL on the website.
My current solution that is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /?test=1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `^$` matches a completely empty request path only. And `/?test=1` will always redirect to the root URL. Plus, you will also need to check that the query string is not `test=1` already, otherwise this will create a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask in your question contradicts partly what you show in your attempt. So this is just a guess, more leaning to what you actually ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=1(?:&|$)
RewriteCond ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?test=1 [QSA,END]
```